# Why conda doesn't see the latest version of sqlalchemy package available in the conda-forge channel?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, anaconda, conda, conda-forge

I'm trying to install `sqlalchemy` with conda.

```
conda install -c conda-forge sqlalchemy
```

On the channel website I can see that the latest available version is 2.0.4.

https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/sqlalchemy

However, when I execute the command, `sqlalchemy`'s latest available version is  1.4.39.

```
The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  greenlet           pkgs/main/win-64::greenlet-2.0.1-py310hd77b12b_0
  sqlalchemy         pkgs/main/win-64::sqlalchemy-1.4.39-py310h2bbff1b_0
```

I'm on `win-64`. I'm using `powershell` but also tried conda's `cmd`.

Why conda doesn't see the latest available version?

Answer (score 2):

If not a fresh environment, then it is likely from existing packages having conflicts. Otherwise, if you want a specific or minimum version, express this to Conda:

```
conda install -c conda-forge 'sqlalchemy>=2.0.4'
```

Comment: This didn't work. I had to add `conda-forge` as a channel, set it to strict mode. And then I had massive number of conflicts, so I rebuilt everything from scratch and reinstalled all packages from `conda-forge` channel.
https://github.com/conda-forge/sqlalchemy-feedstock/issues/132#issuecomment-1446994443